# POST request not coming through (MERN)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, xmlhttprequest, axios

I'm using the MERN stack to build an application for the first time.

In order to log HTTP requests I use "morgan".

I managed to send data to mongodb which seems to be working fine. The problem is that my post request is not coming through. It says "pending" for 4 minutes, then fails.

Here's what I think is the relevant part of my code:

"server.js":

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const routes = require("./routes/api");

const MONGODB_URI =
    "...";

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/app", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
    console.log("Mongoose is connected.");
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cors());

app.use(morgan("tiny"));

app.use("/api", routes);

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is starting at ${PORT}`));
```

Then I've put my routes into another file "api.js":

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

const Lane = require("../models/lanes");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    Lane.find({})
        .then(data => {
            res.json(data);
            console.log("Get request successful!");
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error: ", error);
        });
});

router.post("/save", (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    const newLane = new Lane();
    newLane.collection.insertMany(data, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Multiple docs inserted");
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm using axios to send the request. This happens after submitting a form within my application.

reducer function:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "add":
            axios({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/api/save",
                method: "POST",
                data: [...state, { id: uuid(), title: action.title, tasks: [] }]
            })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("Data has been sent to the server");
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    console.log("Internal server error");
                });
            return [...state, { id: uuid(), title: action.title, tasks: [] }];
```

The reducer is being used by my context provider component, which looks like this:

```
export function LanesProvider(props) {
    const [lanes, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultLanes);

    return (
        <LanesContext.Provider value={lanes}>
            <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
                {props.children}
            </DispatchContext.Provider>
        </LanesContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

The "add" method inside my reducer is being called when submitting a form inside another component.

Please let me know if I can add anything to my question that would help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you calling this in component?Also,How this component is connected to redux.? Share that piece of code.

Comment: Do you see the 3 requests in browser developer tools network tab?

Comment: @SuleymanSah It says "pending", so there's no response being sent back I guess and that's why it sends it again? It fails after 4 minutes, then there's no more requests being sent.

Comment: @SuleymanSah No, I little experience with handling http requests to be honest. I added some more code.

Comment: You shouldn't call api in redux reducer.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I see. So where would you put the API call?

Comment: you can use [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not sending any response back to client. Try to modify post method like

```
router.post("/save", (req, res) => {
const data = req.body;
const newLane = new Lane();
newLane.collection.insertMany(data, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err)
    } else {
        console.log("Multiple docs inserted");
        res.send("Multiple docs inserted")
    }
});
});
```